# What should I include in my network mocking function?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I want to test my network request code. Testing is not my strong point, and I'm doing this mainly to get better at creating testable code. I usually use Alamofire, but want to bypass that for unit tests. I have created a protocol like this:

```
protocol NetworkSession {
    func request(
        _ endpoint: Endpoint,
        method: HTTPMethod,
        completion: @escaping (Result<<DataResponse<Any>>, RequestError>) -> ()
    )
}
```

I conform to this protocol in my class `NetworkSessionManager`:

```
final class NetworkSessionManager : NetworkSession {
    func request(
        _ endpoint: Endpoint,
        method: HTTPMethod,
        completion: @escaping (Result<<DataResponse<Any>>, RequestError>) -> ()) {
        guard let url = endpoint.url else {
            return completion(.failure(.couldNotEncode))
        }
        Alamofire.request(url, method: method, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in

                completion(.success(response))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my `BackendClient` class I inject and call my `NetworkSessionManager` like this:

```
private let session: NetworkSession

init(session: NetworkSession = NetworkSessionManager()) {
    self.session = session
}


func someFunction(...) {
    session.request(...)
}
```

Now I know I need to create a mock class that conforms to `NetworkSession`, but I'm not sure what I should do in it? How do I test all the possibilities and returned data? There are different end points on my server that return different types of data. If someone could point me towards the next steps I should take, I'd be very grateful.

```
final class NetworkSessionManagerMock : NetworkSession {
    func request(
        _ endpoint: Endpoint,
        method: HTTPMethod,
        completion: @escaping (Result<<DataResponse<Any>>, RequestError>) -> ()) {
        ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show two examples that can hopefully give you something to start with in mocking out your `NetworkSession`.

First though, you can add additional properties to your mock class that support injecting values to test various cases. I will demonstrate an error situation and a return for now.

```
enum MyError: Swift.Error {
    case failed
}

final class NetworkSessionManagerMock : NetworkSession {
    var myError: MyError?
    var dataResponse: Any? // This should hopefully be typed to something

    func request(
        _ endpoint: Endpoint,
        method: HTTPMethod,
        completion: @escaping (Result<<DataResponse<Any>>, RequestError>) -> ()) { [weak self] in 
        if let myError = self?.myError {
            // Send error with completion handler
        } else if let dataResponse = self?.dataResponse {
            // Send data response
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that you instantiate the mock in your test, then set the variables as needed to test the respective part. Your mock will then proceed normally.

I did not test this code for syntax correctness though, so let me know if there is a mistake in it.